# Vertical bars on screen

Tags: display, intel-graphics, display-resolution, visual-artifacts

I have just bought Lenovo Z570 and installed ubuntu 11.10 on it. I normally work on the machine with a distance of almost 1.5 feet but I can see vertical bars all over the screen. I have shown my laptop to friends but they couldn't see the bars. I on the other hand cannot un-see them even though the pixel bars are small.

My resolution is set to 1366x768.

lshw returns:

```
*-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 09
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:42 memory:d0000000-d03fffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:3000(size=64)
```

I was thinking if its a driver problem because I saw a similar machine on display running windows and I found its display just fine. That machine had:

- Name: AMD Radeon(TM) HD 6620G
- Chipset Type: ATI display adapter
- Approx. Total Memory: 3046 MB
- Display mode: 1366x768 (32-bit) (60/Hz)

I guess my display device is Intel based. Any idea if the problem can be solved or should I return my laptop?

Comment: Do you have contact lenses or astigmatism? Can you get some camera photos, focused with macro if you know how to do it, at various distances? Please don;t use a phone camera; use a real digital camera(point-and-shoot is OK)

Comment: That's weird I have a Z570, use ubuntu 12.04 and have no problems, I'll compare my display output

Comment: capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom

Comment: Joshua do you have same display device? where did you take this info from: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom

Comment: you could try installing 

    sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
 my graphics always worked but this installed the details...

Comment: Joshua, I mean do you have Intel's graphic card or AMD's?

Comment: Obsessive, I don't wear contact lenses and I don't have astigmatism for I have faced this problem with only this laptop. My other laptop and my friend's laptops don't have the same problem. I don't have a point-and-shoot camera right now but as soon as i get one i will share it. However, I took picture of my screen and the windows based lenove z570 in shop with iphone's camera and found that pixels of my laptop are more distance between them as compare to the distance between pixels on the Windows based lenove z570.

Comment: @JoshuaSiret What does Graphics say in your Dash Home > Settings > System Info > Overview? Mine says Intel SandyBridge Mobile.

Comment: yes it does, I have intel HD too. you could try upgrading to 12.04?

Answer (score 1):

My system settings for baltusaj:

[image]

The Graphics section was updated from:

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

But it should work anyway as per default